# C# HttpListener: IE11 does not apply CSS

Tags: c#, html, css, webserver, httplistener

I wrote a simple HttpListener application, which serves an offline html application.
Everything is working fine in firefox, but IE does not apply the style from the css files.
It requests them and I send them back, but it does not apply them...

```
// Construct a response.
List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
    while (br.BaseStream.Position != br.BaseStream.Length)
        bytes.Add(br.ReadByte());
buffer = bytes.ToArray();
// Get a response stream and write the response to it.
response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
response.RedirectLocation = path;
switch (ext)
{
    case "css":
        mime = "text/css";
        break;
    case "js":
        mime = "text/javascript";
        break;
    case "png":
        mime = "image/png";
        break;
    case "jpg":
        mime = "text/jpeg";
        break;
    case "gif":
        mime = "image/gif";
        break;
}
response.AddHeader("content", mime);
using (Stream output = response.OutputStream)
    output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
break;
```

Comment: BTW: You can simplify your code with `File.ReadAllBytes`

Comment: I guess you mean `Content-Type` not `content`

Comment: Sometimes it is that simple!
I can set the content-type with `response.ContentType = mime;`
Awkard -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Eser said,

```
response.ContentType = mime;
```

is the way to go.